# Matching listview header to column dynamically uwp

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp

This is how my listview currently looks, the headers scale well with the relativepanel outside it but the columns stay the same width

```
<Grid Name="ListViewGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="listViewGrid" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Observation ID" />
            </Grid>

            <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Observations}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ListViewGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ObservationID}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

I've removed some things to make it more readable, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it makes no sense if you set only one `ColumnDefinition` in `Grid` like you did in your `listViewGrid` and in the `DataTemplate`. It's not a big problem, I guess you just removed them to make the code more readable, which is very good.

Secondly, in UWP, `Width="{Binding ElementName=ListViewGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"`, `ActualWidth` is not a dependency property, it cannot be used for data binding. You can refer to the **Remarks** of [FrameworkElement.ActualWidth property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I guess what you need is actually to stretch the `ListViewItem`, then you can simply code like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: The documentation for the `ActualWidth` property is actually really confusing. It says that it does have a backing `ActualWidthProperty` dependency property, yet it doesn't work like a typical dependency property (it doesn't raise property change notifications). Can a dependency property even do that? What is it exactly, then?

Comment: @DecadeMoon, consider it as a regular CLR property, I think no one says a dependency property must raise property changed notifications.

Comment: So you're saying it is possible to change a dependency property's value via `DependencyObject.SetValue()` without raising the `PropertyChangedCallback` (in the property metadata) or any registered callbacks (via `DependencyObject.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback()`)?

Comment: @DecadeMoon, what if this property has only GetValue? You can try to set a value to `ActualWidth`.

Comment: The only way to change a dependency property's value is through `SetValue` (AFAIK); even if there is no setter property, its value can still be changed with `SetValue`. UWP doesn't support registering readonly dependency properties (unlike WPF), unless there's some magic happening behind the scenes to control its value which is not exposed in the public UWP interface (this is where my confusion comes from, how can the ActualWidth property have these features while I can't register my own custom property with the same behavior?).

Comment: @DecadeMoon, yes you're absolutely right here. The problem is how it is encapsulated, we don't have rights to access the code for this, same as you (asked once before without any luck, sorry.). We can only guess that there are some internal methods to create a readonly dependency properties in UWP. And my fault here is directly denying it as a bindable property, binding it as source in some scenario actually works, it only doesn't raise property changed notifications as it is declared in doc, in case it doesn't work, I normally consider it not as a dependency property.